Scriptures that advocate that goddess Kamakhya is satisfied by the Bali of goats?
Which scripture and which portion of it , suggests that goddess like Kamakhya and Kali are satisfies by the Bali of animals?
Also what is the idea behind Bali and does the practitioner incur any sin by doing a Bali of the animal? Thank you.

Read Kalikapurana.

@anu thank you.

Based on Aghori Vimalananda, Bali will  incur karmic ink, if done with desire. But Ma can reduce the impact. Assume someone gives Bali to harm someone. So that person can’t  flee from karmic impact.

Chagtushthe Mahabhime Kamakhaye Suravandite

The above verse is a part of Kamakhya Stotra from Yogini Tantra. Further references can be found in Kamakhya Tantra. Chagtushte means one who is satisfied by goats.
